# Does anyone still writes websites from scratch?

Tags: wordpress, web

I'm diving into web design and development. I wrote a couple of website (just client code) from scratch, starting with just a `touch index.html`. Is this practice still used or most of the web is made out of templates, Wordpress or some other expedient?

Comment: Does `touch index.html` mean on the command line? (I know, random comment, but whatevs.)

Comment: @MathSquared11235 yep, I meant creating an empty HTML file and starting from there, then (still manually and still from scratch) adding CSS styling and client side scripting)

Answer (score 3):

I think 3 things are enough to create good websites (showcase websites or small web app):

- Server-side = Understanding a CMS , its structure, and its core functions + Having
  basic server language notions. In the case of this OP (Wordpress-PHP combination is good).
- Client-side : CSS3 + HTML5 + Javascript (Jquery or equivalent).
- AJAX as a 'bridge' between the two sides.

Doing things from scratch without using a CMS is good for knowledge but requires more time.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are 2 questions here:

1) Is this practice still used?

- Yes, you just used it. Browsers will support it, so *someone* out there will be doing it.

2) Is most of the web made out of templates, Wordpress, etc...

- Yes, I would think so.

You could go the other direction and bypass a web server and create a program that responds directly to HTTP requests on port 80, but using a webserver saves you the trouble of programming and allows you to work with files. Using something other than `touch index.html` is just another step beyond that, using a more expedient way to get to the html files you need.

It's not saying that all websites must be *dynamic* - for example, my own blog is written with [middleman](http://middlemanapp.com/), which is very like writing a Rails app except that you compile the app into static HTML files. It's just so much easier to write in something like Markdown that gets generated to a nice page instead of having to edit the HTML by hand.

Comment: That seems a cool solution to me. I just find myself quite uncomfortable with working with so much code written by others and that I don't understand too much. I feel like using a template (not a *templating system*) doesn't give you as much freedom as writing from scratch does. I mean, I know the concept is the same of using an external library when working with a programming language (you don't want to reinvent the wheel), but since web development is more "complete" (you project and design a website) it feels different to me.

Answer (score 0):

One rule : if you are building a quite complex website, you will spend plenty of time to do something (or many things) you could have done themn in seconds.
Writing websites from scratch is a student task/homework.

Comment: I suspected that for larger projects something like Django or Rails is common and practically needed, but still in that cases... Should I write my own CSS? And should I write my HTML templates from scratch? Mine was kind of a "wider" question

Comment: Well, it is allways usefull to have some templates already done and tested to use. This is called "code reuse" either it is for CSS, HTML for client code, or for any other Server code.

Comment: Yep, I got the whole "refactoring" (I don't know if we can call it "refactoring" in this case). It just makes more sense to me when refactoring is applied to programming code: libraries, functions and classes written in a programming language, not a markup one. Since web development is about *designing* and *implementing* a website, doesn't starting from scratch give you a blank canvas, allowing you to be truly free in what you create? Also, I can't see such usefulness in refactoring HTML. I mean, you still have to fill it with your content...

Comment: Refactoring means big changes to code in order to maintain or evolve to newer version. You got it! From scratch code has its advantages and drawbacks. Advantages are to have very good idea on every line of code. Drawbacks are time and productivity.

Comment: I just feel that HTML isn't suitable for refactoring as much as a programming language is. In an HTML template you still have to go through each line of code in order to fill it with your content, but still you're not free to structure your code as you like.